# Reactive meteor template with calculated property

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to implement a class that displays when a user is "online". I have this template helper that uses the `lastSeenAt` date attribute on the user:

```
Template.user.isOnline = function() {
    timeSinceOnline =  (new Date()).getTime() - this.lastSeenAt.getTime()
    if (timeSinceOnline > 2000) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return 'is-online';
    } 
};
```

The last seen at attribute is constantly being updated when a user has the app open.
This problem is that this helper only updates the template when the lastSeenAt attribute changes. So it works when a user comes online but now when the go offline. Is there anyway to make it recalculate or do I have to manually set some kind of "offline" attribute to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a reactive Date data source. Some reactive variable that reports current date and time and updates every second or so causing the recalculations.

One of the ways to do this is to have it in a Session variable:

```
Session.set("currentDate", new Date);
setInterval(function () { Session.set("currentDate", new Date); }, 1000);
```

and later use it in your code:

```
Template.user.isOnline = function() {
    timeSinceOnline =  Session.get("currentDate").getTime() - this.lastSeenAt.getTime()
    if (timeSinceOnline > 2000) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return 'is-online';
    } 
};
```

If it becomes too inefficient you can come up with something similar that involves `Deps.dependency` later.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [timesync](https://atmospherejs.com/package/timesync) package. It provides a reactive data source for the current time, which is also synced with the server time. The syncing with the server time is necessary if the `lastSeenAt` attribute is set by the server or by another user, since you cannot assume that all clients have an accurate clock.

For this purpose (tracking user online state) you could also look at the [user-status](https://atmospherejs.com/package/user-status) package.